# IE9 CSS hover doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

This css works good on every browser except of Explorer 9
The problem is on the :hover 
sometimes it works and sometimes not.
Css:

```
.navSubMenu .mainMenuContent .programItem:hover a.hoverGreen { color: #b3dd0c;  }
.navSubMenu .mainMenuContent .programItem:hover a.hoverWhite { color: #fff; }
.navSubMenu .mainMenuContent .programItem a.hoverWhite:hover { color: #b3dd0c;  } 
.navSubMenu .mainMenuContent .programItem:hover a.hoverRed { color: #A80000; }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="mainMenuContent">
                            <div class="mainMenuContentWrapper">
                                <Adam:Repeater ID="Rpt_Programs" runat="server" DataItemTypeName="Reshet.Objects.ObjectInfo">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="programItem">
                                            <a href="<%#Container.DataItem.Link.HeyperJustLink() %>">
                                                <%#Container.DataItem.MediaMedium %>
                                                <div class="programTitle">
                                                    <%#Container.DataItem.Name%></div>
                                                <a href="<%#Container.DataItem.Link.HeyperJustLink()%>" class="hoverGreen">לאתר</a>
                                                <span class="divider"></span><a href="<%#Container.DataItem.ItemLink.HeyperJustLink() %>"
                                                     class="hoverWhite">לפרק האחרון</a>
                                                <div class="addToFavWrapper">
                                                    <%-- <img class="addToFavBtn" src="<%=SiteUrl %>/images/n_Images/Headers/plus_normal.png" alt="">
                                    <img class="addToFavBtn_over" src="<%=SiteUrl %>/images/n_Images/Headers/plus_over.png" alt="">--%>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </Adam:Repeater>
                            </div>
                            <a href="<%=SiteUrl %>/Shows/VOD/" class="allBtn greenBtn">לכל התוכניות</a>
                        </div>
```

When I move the mouse over the div, the hover sometimes happed and sometime not, sometime get stacked till i move the mouse over again and then it sometimes released.
So it is not works properly at all.

Comment: what happens when it is not working? please be more detailed it will help to solve the case

Comment: The problem is probably specific to your markup. Can you show HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `<a>` tag inside `.programItem` is not closed in your code:

```
<div class="programItem">
    <a href="<%#Container.DataItem.Link.HeyperJustLink() %>">
```

Also you are targeting `.navSubMenu .mainMenuContent .programItem:hover a.hoverGreen` however there is no parent of `.navSubMenu` in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try using strict HTML 4 doctype as in this article: http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762

Though it says IE7 in the article, this fix solved the problem for others who were having the same issue in IE9.

Comment: it is already have   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Answer (score 0):

you need to move `:hover` to the `a` elements, example:

```
.navSubMenu .mainMenuContent .programItem a.hoverGreen:hover { color: #b3dd0c; }
.navSubMenu .mainMenuContent .programItem a.hoverWhite:hover { color: #fff; }
.navSubMenu .mainMenuContent .programItem a.hoverWhite:hover { color: #b3dd0c; } 
.navSubMenu .mainMenuContent .programItem a.hoverRed:hover { color: #A80000; }
```

Comment: It miss the point - when i hover on div with class .programItem , i want to change the color of the a.hoverGree